# "Magic keys" to force a reboot of a hung macOS system via root-level reboot command?

Tags: macos, monterey, reboot, force-quit

Have had some problems from time to time on macOS 12.x where it hangs indefinitely. I'm working with Apple engineers on a resolution, but I'd like to figure out how to set up a method to send the equivalent of a `sudo reboot` to the kernel via a crazy key combination so that when apps and everything hang for hours on end I can break out of the situation more safely than just holding in the power button.

Anyone see such a trick that still works for macOS 12?

Answer (score 1):

There are no non-obvious magic keys for this. Apple documents these publicly.

**Option-Shift-Command-Q** will log you out immediately.

If that doesn’t work, try a forced - no questions asked - reboot.

**Control–Command–Power** button

Ideally the machine won’t be stuck in a way that prevents these from being processed. As a last resort, try to `ssh` in to restart without needing the keyboard processing to be unblocked.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

Comment: Yeah, `ssh` is hung at that point to which I'm referring. Basically I need a kernel-level key capture that triggers the kernel to do as safe of a reboot as possible and as close as possible to a simple `sudo reboot` that doesn't just obliterate the fs.

Comment: There is none if the keys listed above and ssh are blocked. You’ve sadly lost the chance to get another filesystem sync at that point. Journaling on the FS will prevent the FS from becoming corrupt at the cost of whatever pages are not flushed cleanly.

Comment: yeah I kinda had the same thought process, but I suppose my only remaining option would be to jump into kernel debugging and remote `gdb` connection to trace out the issue and to perhaps see if there's another option at a deeper level. Sure wish Apple would capture panics better and segregate subsystems further. For example one could push the fs access above the kernel panic handling layer via mach, but it seems to be something they've never done with the capabilities of their mach foundation. <shrug>

Comment: Things were good for a while on OS X server with proper watchdog timeout reboots, but even panics  cause so much “panic” in most people I get why it’s suppressed so much behind developer tools and ulimit are needed to generate cores when we want them